# How to use Kodein with Conductor in Android?

Tags: android, kodein, conductor

I want to use both Conductor and Kodein in my application.
The problem is that both the application context and the activity are null on the Controller setup and I can't access Kodein instance.

```
class SetupNavigationController: Controller(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein: Kodein by closestKodein(applicationContext!!)
    //    val kodein = (activity as MainActivity).kodein
    val someInstance: SomeClass by kodein.instance()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kodein is lazy by default especially because the applicationContext is null at the time of class instanciation and set later by the system.

You need to use the lazy syntax, so that `applicationContext` will only be accessed when needded:

```
class SetupNavigationController: Controller(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein: Kodein by kodein { applicationContext!! }
    val someInstance: SomeClass by kodein.instance()
}
```

Comment: It's not working, I still get the null pointer exception on application context

Comment: I found what the problem is, you have to remove kodein from kodein.instance() as if you access it by kodein, it won't be lazy anymore.

Comment: val someInstance: SomeClass by instance() 
would do the job